# tcp: where is the 3way handshake implemented

Tags: tcp, linux-kernel, kernel

Who implements the 3way handshake process (syn - syn+ack - ack) , the operating system (kernel) auto, the developer of the app ?

In the web server <--> web browser environment , was apache programmed to send a SYN+ACK pachet upon the arrival or the SYN packet  ? I can;t figure it out , because I know how to send a raw packet with scapy but i don;t know who manages this ...

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Who implements the 3way handshake process (syn - syn+ack - ack) , the
>   operating system (kernel) auto, the developer of the app ?

Not the app of course.It is done but the implemenetation of TCP/IP stack part of your OS

> In the web server <--> web browser environment , was apache programmed
>   to send a SYN+ACK pachet upon the arrival or the SYN packet ?

Application servers use underlying OS facilities for the network communication. The part you describe is completely done by the TCP/IP implementation of the OS

> I know how to send a raw packet

Yes but when sending a raw packet you can only "form" the data in the frame which usually are not "visible"/accesible. You don't define a flow or have any other control.

Comment: Are developers able to implement their own TCP mechanism with their app ?

Comment: Then how is python-scapy able to construct a packet and send it with all king of field values ... ? Does that not use the underlying OS facillities ?

Comment: From the documentation, python-scapy interacts with the Linux kernel, possibly using libpcap and the likes, similar to how Wireshark works. Lower lever APIs do exist (i.e. sending raw packets), but sometimes(?) they require root privilege.

Comment: @pufos:I am not sure what you really ask here.Generally a network application at the lowest level uses sockets which use the TCP stack implementation of the OS.This part is transparent to programmers.There are application though that could "manipulate" the TCP in order e.g to attack a network or a server.These operate on raw level and can send e.g. multiple SYN etc to flood a server.Also there are others that facilitate in monitoring network flow.But is this what you are looking for?Because I thought that you wanted to ask about network programming in general.

Comment: @pufos: It uses raw sockets, which are orthogonal to TCP/UDP

Comment: @Krumelur .. I'm pursuing CISCO CCNA and next CCNP and my brain in blown away by this "simple" thing. I'm always thinking how phisically the flow is done and I came across 3way handshake that I don't know how does it phisically work because I want to fully understand this process.

Comment: @user384706 If the raw packets does not use the kernel implementation (because I can send a raw packet with ip of 127.0.0.1 that will never happend if I let the OS do this) how does the app implementation phisically (and I mean the compiled code .. etc) can do that ?

Comment: @pufos:I am not sure I really get your question.The programmer doesn't care or need to know exactly how the bits are transmitted.In the application level (talking about e.g. an application running in Tomcat) the application data are passed to the TCP stack and then all the rest are done by OS as a magic black box.The response is handled the same way.The OS notifies that there is a message in the stack and it is passed up the application level. Perhaps you should also review the OSI model?Does this answer your question?

Comment: @user384706 I am a programmer and also learning cisco ccna, ccnp networking ... so as a programmer now i need to know how that works. I know that it's transparent to the programmer but now i really need to know the "behind the scenes"